# TFS Get Specific Version addin

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-addins, vsx

I am looking for an addin that will allow me to click a button on the VS toolbar and the following actions should happen.

1. On the highlighted project/folder/item from either Source Control Explorer or Solution Explorer, do a 'Get Specific Version'
2. Click those 2 checkboxes, hit the 'Get' button on that dialog

[alt text http://img367.imageshack.us/img367/9162/getspecificversionyp9.jpg](http://img367.imageshack.us/img367/9162/getspecificversionyp9.jpg)

As I find myself doing this so often (I trust it more than the usual 'Get Latest version'), I wanted to see anyone else has already thought about this.
If not, I am going to have to write an VS addin myself.

Comment: @danielMann don't forget to vote to close off topic questions that you edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you just want to make sure developers are starting their changes on the most recent version?

If that is the case, and you are using VSTS 2008 and TFS 2008, then using the "[Get Latest Version on Checkout](http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2007/12/TFS-Get-Latest-Version-on-Check-Out-in-VS2008.aspx)" setting of both is probably your answer, if you aren't then the "[CheckOut and Get Latest Version](http://www.codeplex.com/TfsAddInCheckOut)" is what you investigate. (note, if you are using VSTS 2008 and TFS 2005, you'll need to do the compile yourself, see the notes at the bottom of the home page)

Buck Hodges has [a post](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2005/08/20/454140.aspx) why this wasn't built into 2005 and isn't the default action in 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to your question, but why do you find you are needing to do a Get Specific all the time?  Are you editing or deleting files locally outside of Visual Studio without check-ing the files out first?

If you have both of these options checked then you will be downloading all the latest versions of the files every time you do a get latest - which isn't going to give you optimal performance.

Comment: Yes, I might be editing/deleting outside of VS sometimes, and I've seen (back in 05 TFS) that get latest doesn't bring down everything. I am not really worried about performance.